# Visual Studio Forms: Sometimes, selecting a data grid cell doesn't set the cell's Selected property to true?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I am working with a data grid for Visual Studio forms. When I select a given cell, I want to keep track of the index of the row that cell is on, using the following code:

```
selectedRows.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.RowCount; i++)
{
            if (dataGrid[column, i].Selected)
            {                    
                selectedRows.Add(i);
            }
}
```

This works 80% of the time. However, occasionally, when I select the name cell of a row, it highlights the cell blue, which leads me to believe I selected it, but the index is not added to selectedRows. Is there something I am missing here?

Am I correct in assuming that sometimes the cells Selected property is simply not set to true, which is causing this error, even though I have clearly selected the cell?

P.S. I have checked that the "column" variable is correct.

Comment: in dataGridView properties (MultiSelected) =False and (SelectionMode)=CellSelect 
dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex -- get Row Index
dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow -- get Row
dataGridView1 .CurrentRow  -- get Row

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cell click event and do something like this:

```
private void Datagridview1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.RowIndex;
        if (!selectedRows.Exists(x =>x == index))
        {
           selectedRows.Add(index)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will not work for my purposes since I need to check for multiple selections, and otherwise this is basically the same code as I have above. The problem is that the cell appears to be selected in the form, but the cell.Selected property is set to false.